# Modification in the permissions in the server's files asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, razor, file-io

I'd like to create and delete directories in the project's directory for an asp.net mvc application like

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"Projet");
```

or

```
Directory.Delete(path);
```

but an exception `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` is appears.

Why this happens? how can i do to create and delete files and directories in the project's directory?

Comment: Is `path` a file or a directory? If it's a file, you should use `File.Delete`.

Comment: `path` is a directory zipped

Comment: Have you tried using `File.Delete` instead of `Directory.Delete`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30853/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-wgraham)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting directories can cause an AppDomain recycle, which you definitely don't want if you're using session at all.  According to the comments, though, it sounds as if you just need to delete a file.  To delete a file you can simply use `File.Delete(filePath);`

Comment: i uploaded a zipped file and i have a function of extraction : if i put the new  directory in the project's directory the exception appears else if put outside it is created without problem.for the delete the same exception

Comment: The UnauthorizedAccessException likely means that w3wp.exe (IIS worker process) doesn't have permissions to delete the files or folders.  You'll need to provide adequate permissions to the folders to be able to perform these actions.  Just keep in mind that deleting folders can restart the application, which will blow away any session data you may have.

Comment: You don't modify the permissions in the worker process, you modify the permissions on disk.  Use windows explorer, right-click on the folder or file you want to modify, select properties and then the Security tab.